# Trigger hashchange event on button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call the same action whenever the button is clicked, or the hash changed event occurred. Even if the hash changed event means just loading the page for the first time and redirecting to something like #something.

What I had so far, is basically duplicated code. The same code for a hashchange event, and for button clicked. I am looking for a solution not to have the code duplicated, but to call the **hashchange event from a button clicked event**. Here is my code so far.

**main.js**

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {

    // get User from the URL
    var user = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    // update the value in a text input with new ASIN
    document.getElementById('asin_input').value = asin;

        $.getJSON("/api/user/"+user, function (data) {
            // ...
        });

}).trigger('hashchange');


/*
 * Whenever a button "Search!" is clicked, this function gets called.
 */
element.addEventListener('click', function () {

    var user = $('#user_input').val();

        $.getJSON("/api/user/"+user, function (data) {
            // ...
        });
});
```

Now the entire thing inside getJSON, and including the getJSON is duplicated, so I would want just the onClick calling/triggering the hashchange, which triggers getJSON. How to do this?

Comment: Put it in its own function and call that one from inside both handlers?

Comment: Yes, but it would be better to have just one handler calling the other.

Comment: Use `$(window).trigger('hashchange')` in the click function.

Comment: "As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated." Just for future refernce you'll probably want to swap over to `on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/